# Efficient serialization/deserialization of nested models with django rest framework

Tags: django, serialization, nested, django-rest-framework, deserialization

I have a django model that can be nested recursively:

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models

class Node(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   parent = models.ForeignKey('Node', related_name='children', null=True)
```

Nested models commonly have ~100 nodes in my application.

I am using django rest framework for serialization/deserialization:

*serializers.py*

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Node
from django.db import models

class NodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # Recursive serializers not supported, so use a blank one
    children = serializers.Serializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Node
        fields = ('name', 'children')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Remove nested objects to handle separately
        children = validated_data.pop('children', [])
        node = Node.objects.create(
            # parent is null only on the root node
            parent=self.context.get('parent'),
            **validated_data)
        for child_data in children:
            s = NodeSerializer(data=child_data
                                context={'parent': node})
            s.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            s.save()
        return node

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        if not isinstance(instance, models.Model):
            # If the Serializer was instantiated with data instead of a model,
            # "instance" is an OrderedDict.
            return instance
        else:
            # This renders simple fields
            representation = super(NodeSerializer, self)\
                .to_representation(instance)
            # Then recursively render nested models
            representation['children'] = [NodeSerializer(child).data
                                          for child in instance.children.all()]
            return representation

    def validate(self, data):
        # serializers.Serializer couldn't validate children,
        # so we validate here
        children = self.initial_data.get('children')
        if children:
            self._validate_children(children)
            data.update({'children': children})
        return data

    def _validate_children(self, value):
        # TODO
        pass
```

With this, you can deserialize nested models like this:

```
s = NodeSerializer(data={
    'name': 'grandma', 
    'children': [{
        'name': 'dad', 
        'children': [{'name': 'me'}]
        }, {
        'name': 'uncle joe', 
        'children': [{'name': 'cousin frank'}]
        }
    ]})
s.is_valid()
m = s.save()
print m.children.first().children.first().name
# me
```

And you can serialize like this:

```
s = NodeSerializer(m)
print s.data
# {'name': u'grandma', 'children': [{'name': u'dad', 'children': [{'name': u'me', 'children': []}]}, {'name': u'uncle joe', 'children': [{'name': u'cousin frank', 'children': []}]}]}
```

This works, but both serialization and deserialization make a separate query for each node. At about 0.15 s per trip to the database, requests time out for models with many nodes.

Serialization can be made faster by doing one of these:

1. Render with just the immediately connected children ID's, and require the client to explicitly request each child. Use prefetch_related on children to get them all in a single query.
2. Create another ForeignKey field that points from each child to the root node, then use prefetch_related to look up all nested children at once.

What about deserialization? Is there a way to avoid a separate query for each node? If not, are there other good strategies to avoid timing out requests?

Comment: Personally, I would prefer to not (de)serialize nested models, and instead do it all explicitly. Related article on prefetch_related which you've probably seen: http://ses4j.github.io/2015/11/23/optimizing-slow-django-rest-framework-performance/.

Answer (score 0):

You should override the default view and fetch by yourself the data from the database to take advantage of any tip on your data models. Also MPTT algorithme may help here.

Also note that you can not go under O(n) as you'll need to scan the full list of nodes to serialize / deserialize.

Edit:
I realize that you may refer to the DB query. If so, MPTT or prefetch_related / custom data queries should help

Comment: Exactly, I'm interested in avoiding a separate query for each node. Edited for clarity.

Comment: MPTT seems to get to the crux of the problem. Looking into implementation details to see how to make it work for my case. prefetch_related helps for serialization but I don't think it helps with deserializing.